# Minecraft crashes on start with following stacktrace (Whats the best way of fixing it)

Tags: java, minecraft, stack-trace

https://pastebin.com/2trkexp7

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000203004c7960, pid=12684, tid=17604
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-32931 (17.0.3+7) (build 17.0.3+7-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-32931 (17.0.3+7-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000203004c7960
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/microsoft/openjdk/issues
#
```

Whats the best way of fixing that exception.
Happend on a clean windows 11 install.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error, for me it was graphics card drivers. If you have AMD 22.5.1 worked for me.